# Issue with GROUP_CONCAT and output to csv

Tags: mysql

I am facing an issue with GROUP_CONCAT and exporting the results to csv.

Consider the following table
Search Results
 with columns search Id | Description | Votes | search category

```
and consider the following data in the table
1|java, beans|2|java
2|serialization|3| java
3|jquery| 1|javascript
4|mysql joins|5| database
```

I need the output in the following format

```
Search Category| description1 | description 2 | votes 1 | votes 2
java           |java,beans    | serialization | 2       | 3
javascript     |jquery         |              | 1
database       | mysqljoins    |              | 5
```

I need to output this data into a csv file.

I have written the following query
select category, GROUP_CONCAT(description), GROUP_CONCAT(votes) from search_results group by search_category into outfile '/tmp/out.csv' fields terminated by ','  enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';

However, following are the issues
-The above query returns one column each for description and votes which displays the comma separated values . I need separate columns for each of the values(as shown in the desired output)
- for the category javascript, the output is returned in the format

```
javascript|jquery|5<br/>
```

I will need the out put in the format
    javascript|jquery| | 5| |

There should be a placeholder for the empty values

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  s1.search_category
  , s1.description AS description1
  , ISNULL(s2.description, '') AS description2
  , s1.votes AS votes1
  , ISNULL(s2.votes, '') AS votes2
FROM search_results AS s1
LEFT OUTER JOIN search_results AS s2 ON s2.search_category = s1.search_category
WHERE s1.search_id < s2.search_id
INTO OUTFILE ...
```

LEFT JOINing the table to its self will give you the second column if there is one. If there isn't one, the values will be NULL and the ISNULL will return spaces (or whatever else you want).

If there are more than 2 rows with the same search_category, you will get more than one row in the output which might not be what you're after.

Comment: The solution will not work in my case because the number of results for a category is dynamic ,so the number of columns for displaying the description and votes is dynamic

Comment: So your output will have varying numbers of columns (smelly) or you want all rows padded to the max number of columns?